# have to install make in mac?

Tags: mac

when i use make, it doesnt find the program

how do you install it in a mac?

Comment: You shouldn't ask the same question on two sites: http://serverfault.com/questions/102396/installing-make-in-mac

Comment: how could you see that?

Comment: Well, he found the question. And then posted his comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the Developer Tools disk.

---

I don't know how you get a new DVD.

You *might* be able to build a working development environment without the Developer Tools use [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/). But I have never tried that.

Answer (score -2):

You can get `make` with the latest version of Xcode, available from Apple's [Mac Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/mac/), or through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

Comment: MacPorts requires Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, Nerdling. I had no idea — I guess I've always had the developer tools on machines before installing MacPorts on 'em.